# How do I loop a code over all columns in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, roc, auc, proc-r-package

Package:

```
install.packages("pROC") 

library(pROC)
```

The dataset looks like this: [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAElT.png) #Apologies for not including the actual dataset

I am trying to apply the roc() code across all columns starting from column 3:

```
roc1 <- roc(df$Immunoscore,df$col_name)
```

Currently, I was thinking of doing a `lapply` method.

```
list_of_AUC <- lapply(3:ncol, function(i){

roc(RD0161_Final$Immunoscore, RD0161_Final[,i])})
```

I'm getting a mistake:

> Error in 3:ncol : NA/NaN argument

Is there a better method? please help!

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
lapply(RD0161_Final[,3:9], function(i) {
      roc(RD0161_Final[,2] ~ i)
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify the column name

```
lapply(RD0161_Final[,3:9], function(i) {
      roc(RD0161_Final[["Immunoscore"]] ~ i)
}
```

Comment: Hi David. I believe your suggestion code is incomplete

Comment: Why do you say that? You can assign the results of the lapply to an object i.e. `res <- lapply()` if that is what you are referring to. The code I have provided is equivalent to the code you provided in your question in that its another way of doing the same thing but more amenable to using lapply.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code -

```
list_of_AUC <- lapply(RD0161_Final[-(1:2)], function(x) roc(RD0161_Final$Immunoscore, x))
```

You can also use `3:ncol(RD0161_Final)` to subset the dataframe.

```
list_of_AUC <- lapply(RD0161_Final[3:ncol(RD0161_Final)], function(x) roc(RD0161_Final$Immunoscore, x))
```

Comment: However, the original code: 'roc1 <- roc(RD0161_Final$Immunoscore,RD0161_Final$`colname`)' is required.

Comment: You can't use `$` with a variable name. If you want to use column names you can do `list_of_AUC <- lapply(names(RD0161_Final[-(1:2)]), function(x) roc(RD0161_Final$Immunoscore, RD0161_Final[[x]]))`

Comment: I received this error. Error in roc.default(RD0161_Final$Immunoscore, RD0161_Final[[x]]) : Predictor must be numeric or ordered.

Comment: Please provide data in a reproducible format which can be easily copied and tested on the answer. We cannot copy data  from an image. This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269